# What content does "LA Noire - Complete" contain over "LA Noire - Standard" for PS3

Tags: ps3, la-noire

Right now Standard is available on amazon for $11 while the complete version is $70. What additional content is available in Complete? I assume it's DLC material. If so, how much does the combined DLC material cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the L.A. Noire Rockstar Pass (which contains all DLC) is only [$12 USD](http://www.gamestop.com/ps3/dlc/la-noire-rockstar-pass/91352) (sorry, I can't find a PSN link for it), buying the complete edition for $70 is a ripoff.

Comment: @Daenyth I've changed the link to GameStop now.

Comment: @Daenyth Having said that, you should also be able to buy it [directly through PSN](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/06/02/l-a-noire-downloadable-content-now-available-on-psn/).